# PHP - Twilio SMS MySQL Multiple Numbers - Only sends to first row

Tags: php, mysql, twilio, twilio-php

First I run this code to get the phone number, first name and last name for the Twilio SMS.

```
$users_query = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name, phone_no from users WHERE phone_no!=''");
    $users = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($users_query))
    {
        $users[]=$row;
    }
```

Then I use this to send the SMS, which should send to all the numbers on the column phone_no.

```
foreach($users as $user)
    {
        $people = array(
            //$phone_no => $full_name
            $user['phone_no'] => $user['first_name'].' '. $user['last_name']
        );
    }

    // Step 5: Loop over all our friends. $number is a phone number above, and 
    // $name is the name next to it
    foreach ($people as $number => $name) {
        try{
            $sms = $client->account->messages->create(

            // the number we are sending to - Any phone number
            $number,

            array(
```

Currently the SMS is only sent the first rows phone number. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal ... Do this

```
$people = [];
foreach($users as $user)
{
  $people[] = array(
    'full_name' => $user['first_name'].' '. $user['last_name'],
    'phone_no' => $user['phone_no'],
  );
}

foreach ($people as $one) {

    $name = $one['full_name'];
    $phone = $one['phone_no'];

    $sms = $client->account->messages->create(
        $phone,

        array(
            'from' => "+15017250604", 
            'body' => "Hey $name, Monkey Party at 6PM. Bring Bananas!"
        )
    );
    echo "Sent message to $name";
 }
```

You should declare $people as an array. Then in the loop you have to add to $people this []

Comment: I get this error and no SMSs are sent to anyone. [HTTP 400] Unable to create record: The 'To' number 0 is not a valid phone number.https://choiceinsurances.com/sandbox/stripe/form.php?tokenid=a9c37126-44c3-4345-a60c-173101631425&ntoken=MA==[HTTP 400] Unable to create record: The 'To' number 1 is not a valid phone number.https://choiceinsurances.com/sandbox/stripe/form.php?tokenid=a9c37126-44c3-4345-a60c-173101631425&ntoken=MQ==\n...

Comment: Are you sure about the phone number format ? It shoul be intl phone number

Comment: The script works but will only send it to the first row I have. I get the text OK.

Comment: I'm not sure, it's breaking my code the updates I've made.

Comment: Obviously im not seing whats wrong with the update. Make a try catch then. And let me know what's wrong

Comment: We've fixed everything on our end. Thank you for your help.